# Outlook Template How To

Tags: templates, outlook, ms-office, html-email

I am building out a template/stationary for outlook, and I want to include a place in the template where an individuals signature will automatically populate within the template itself, not at the bottom. Has anyone ever done that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot integrate dynamic content with stationary. For replies, the signature placement will always occur only at the point between the reply and the quoted email.

Comment: Eric is correct, you cannot, through the editor, add in dynamic fields, you would need to create a Visual Basic (VBA) script or macro to do this.  It CAN be done, but for the significant amount of work and time needed, it might be better to try and source to third party options (like Exclaimer or similar)